# search a file and create a new file only if a condition is met

Tags: command-line

I have a logfile and I want to search it for a string and only if that string is found a new file to be created.
How can I achieve this, sed doenst seem to be fitting in this case.

Comment: Use `grep` to search. The `-q` option will suppress all output, and return  match/nonmatch via `grep`'s exit code, which is easily testable.

Comment: It might be helpful to tell us what the condition is.

Answer (score 16):

Tack a short circuit evaluation after `grep`:

```
grep -q 'search_pattern' /file && : >/newfile
```

- `grep -q` produces no output on STDOUT, just exits with exit status `0` if the pattern is found on the file
- If the pattern is found (`&&`), create a file `/newfile` by `: >/newfile`.

---

You could also go for the usual `touch /newfile` approach, or on `bash`, an empty redirection -- `>/newfile` would do too.

Just to note, if the file already exists then `touch` would only the change the relevant timestamps without truncating the file. And the empty redirection `>/newfile` is not supported on all shells on-the-go (e.g. in `zsh`), where you have to manually send the EOF.

Comment: What does the `:` do ?

Comment: @George `:` is shorthand for `true`, it's a no-op command that always exits with exit status 0.

Comment: @heemayl This worked best till this day

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun:

```
python3 -c "if 'string' in open('logfile').read(): open('newfile', 'wt')"
```

where `'string'` is replaced by the string (condition), `'logfile'` is replaced by the path to the logfile, `'newfile'` is replaced by the actual path to the file to create, all in single quotes, lik in the example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk with its `system()` command. If the `/pattern/` is found, the codeblock `{}` will be executed, in this case we call `touch /tmp/my_file.txt` via `system()` command.

The example below shows creating a temporary file if there is my user present in `/etc/passwd`.

```
$ awk '/xieerqi/{system("touch /tmp/my_file.txt")}' /etc/passwd

$ ls -l /tmp/my_file.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 1月  25 07:58 /tmp/my_file.txt
```

Alternatively, we could use redirection to file:

```
 awk '/xieerqi/{f="/tmp/my_file.txt";print "" > f;close(f)}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the you want a new empty file, or if you need more complex processing to create the file.

If the former, the reply by @heemayl is spot on.

Otherwise, use an if-statement:

```
if grep -q 'search_pattern' /file
then
    # Create your file here
fi
```